# How to call function defined in parent component in child component on KeyDown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, reactjs-flux

```
var B = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="button" onClick={this.props.saveFunction} />        
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var A = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <B saveFunction={this.save} />        
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: function(){
        //Save code
    }
});
```

Hello,
I am working in facebook react js.
I have created two components wherein A is parent component and B is child component.
I have written Save function in A and passing its reference as "props" to component B.
I am passing this Save function reference to "onClick" event of button rendered from B and I also want to save the values when user press the ENTER button.
So, I am trying to pass the same reference to "onKeyDown" event of same button.
But, its not working.
Contstraint is: I can't shift save function from A to B.
Please let me know how I can achieve this.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I you pass `this.save` function to child element it loses it's context (JavaScript tires to execute `save` function when keyword `this` points to `B` element).

Bind that function with `.bind(this)` like:
`<B saveFunction={this.save.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Hi, on mouse click (onClick event) its working fine. My requirement is, I want to call function defined in parent component when I hit "ENTER" key.